# Drupal show menu in English and Spanish with www in the URL

Tags: routes, panels, i18n-l10n

I use:

- Drupal 7.23
- i18n-7x-1.10
- Language icons 7.x-1.0
- APC 7.x-1.0-beta4

I have activated the Menu Translations sub module for translate the items of main menu.
My language negotion is by URL.

When I enter to my site with: http://domain.com, the menu translate works fine. It only shows the items for the active language.

But when I enter to my url with: http://www.domain.com, not work the translate. All main menu items appear (in all languages). No respect the Negotiation for URL.

Then, to inspect my settings on the main menu I have the following:

- MULTILINGUAL OPTIONS
- Translation mode
  --- Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized.

But, when I set this configuration (in mode admin) with the URL: www.domain.com
and then click on save button, appear the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method i18n_object_wrapper::strings_update() in /sites/all/modules/contrib/i18n/i18n_string/i18n_string.module on line 851`

But, no appear when I save this configuration with the URL: http://domain.com

Moreover, with "www" option disappears the option for translate menu items. So, all items that were translated earlier are considered as a normal item menu and shows all.
This does not happen when only income, "http://"

### Example

(http://domain.com/en - version english)
Item1-en Item2-en Item3-en

(http://domain.com/es - version spanish)
Item1-es Item2-es Item3-es

(http://www.domain.com - version spanish or english)
Item1-en Item2-en Item3-en Item1-es Item2-es Item3-es

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

[image: Screenshot3]

[image: Screenshot4]

Comment: Did you set the default methods to set the language? I think the problem is not with www but with the language settings. Visit admin/config/regional/language/configure to see your language detection.

Comment: @Gladiator I set in my configuration `Method Detection by URL`. I think that is a problem with i18n module. With `http` works fine. But, with `http://www.` No

Comment: @Gladiator I update the description of my question.